# What is the role of induction in the proof of König's Lemma?

Tags: graph-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am looking at this version of König's Lemma: let $T$ be a tree with countably infinite nodes, and each node has finite degree. Then, $T$ has a simple path containing countably infinite number of nodes.

From what I understand, we can let $S$ be the set of all nodes with infinite descendants. $S$ is nonempty since the root node is in it. Furthermore, we can define a relation $R$ such that $xRy \implies y$ is a child of $x$. Let $a \in S$, then since $a$ has infinite descendants, there must be a $b \in S$ such that $a Rb$. So, this relation is total or entire.

We can then apply the [axiom of dependent choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) on $S$ to get a sequence of nodes $(x_n)$, such that $x_n R x_{n+1}$. This sequence is the simple path required for the lemma.

However, I have read several [proofs that use induction](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/cs513/PropCalcCompactness.pdf). Don't these proofs also require the axiom of dependent choice? If so, why are we using induction, which gives a simple path of length $n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, instead of directly defining the relation like I did above?

Comment: The question is not about the role of induction, as much as the role of the axiom of choice (or rather dependent choice).

Comment: From a second order number theory point of view, König's Lemma is in $ACA_0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics for the definition of $ACA_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two points here.

1. Induction and dependent choice work hand by hand. Dependent choice is exactly the choice mechanism which allows to pass from "for every finite $n$ there is an extension", which we can usually show using induction, to a coherent infinite sequence.

   Meaning if you prove something like "If $x_n$ is chosen, choose $x_{n+1}$ as such and such" then the guarantee that the entire sequence $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ even exists is due to Dependent Choice.
2. If the underlying set can be well-ordered. For example, it is $\Bbb N$, then one can actually use induction to define the sequence, and no appeal to the axiom of choice is needed, because the induction process chooses the points of the sequence uniformly.

(I should also point out that compactness arguments also require a bit of the axiom of choice in their general settings.)

Comment: Dependent Choice says that given a nonempty set and a total/entire relation on the set, we have a sequence with certain properties. How does induction give us that set and the relation, so that we can apply dependent choice?

Comment: Well, Dependence Choice has many, many equivalent formulations. I like the more general (more because it easily extends to uncountable cardinals too): If $S$ is a non-empty set, and $R$ is a binary relation, whose domain is finite sequences from $S$, and its range is elements of $S$, such that for every $f\colon n\to S$ there is some $s\in S$ such that $f\mathrel{R}s$, then there is a function $f\colon\omega\to S$ such that for all $n$, $f\upharpoonright n\mathrel{R}f(n)$. There are also formulations using trees, and Zorn-like formulations. [...]

Comment: [...] The key point is that you don't necessarily define the relation on the set of nodes itself, but rather on a set of finite sequences which satisfy a particular property ordered by inclusion, for example, then an infinite sequence translates back to an infinite sequence in the graph/tree.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was what I was missing: that there is an equivalent formulation of dependent choice that can be used with induction. +1 and accepted.